# juju ERROR subprocess encountered error code 255

Tags: juju

When I try to add a node to juju model, in my case it's called "Landscape.maas" as showed in this picture

[image]

received the following error:

```
ERROR subprocess encountered error code 255 (Permission denied (publickey).)
```

the command used is:

```
 $: juju add-machine ssh:ubuntu@Landscape.maas --model landscapelab
```

any suggest? thanks

Comment: It's because the public key of the machine from where you're running 'juju add-machine...' command is not added to the Landscape.maas machine.

Comment: You can add ssh-keys of other machines for the new nodes from the 'User Preferences' page in MAAS WebUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved that thanks to Junaid's suggest